# blank screen from power save on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: 17.04

This is a new custom box with AMD Ryzen 5 and an old ATI graphics card, running 17.04. This problem didn't occur until it started running a long, heavy compute job overnight. Touching the mouse or hitting a key causes the monitor to wake up, but it only displays a blank screen.

SSH into the system shows the job is still progressing. After googling for a few hours, still haven't found a way to get back the lock screen without killing the lightdm or force a system reboot, both of which will lose the processing results on the GUI.

BTW, before this, the first time the compute job was run, after coming out of power save mode, the display flashed on/off, but the keyboard was locked. So, wasn't able to unlock the screen and wound up just forcing a reboot. Don't know if these two phenomenons are related though.

Appreciate if anyone could help here, and also advise whether this may be bug that needs to be reported to Ubuntu.

Thx,

Comment: ubuntu dropped amd support since 16.04

Comment: I've had this problem on a few different computers, pressing a key or moving the mouse wakes the machine but the screen doesn't get turned back on. I think it is a driver issue. anyway to see what s happening try plugging in an external monitor.

Comment: This is running on an external monitor, which is connected to the old ATI graphics card. For now, it's rebooted and the lock screen disabled. There hasn't been any issue running this way, other than the constantly-on screen.